# GitKraken - Cannot redirect from www.gitlab.com to gitlab.com

Tags: git, gitkraken

I started to get that issue a couple of days ago but can't find out what's the real issue... Any idea?

`Cannot redirect from 'www.gitlab.com' to 'gitlab.com'`

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: Remove `www.` from remote URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different stuff and ended up just re cloning... I don't know why it suddenly behaves like this

Answer (score 0):

The origin have to be specified as : https://gitlab.com/... not https://www.gitlab.com/...

The same for GitHub.